# How to setup GA4 account structure for multi-domain project

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-4, accounts

we are currently setting up the Google Analytics 4 for our system websites, and we have a dilemma about the account structure.
We have:

- 2 websites for customers from different countries (domain.sk, domain.cz). Customers can see all the basic information and register here.
- 1 system administration websites for both countries (domain.com). Customers can manage their accounts here.
- 1 website for all the manuals to our system (help.domain.com).

The question is: How to structure our Analytics 4 account for the best results and possible retargetting in the future?
Is it better to set it all under one property and just devide them into individual Data streams? Or set individual property for each of them?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

**Disclaimer.** First thing first, we don't typically recommend using GA4 at this time. It's severely lacking comparing to UA despite google's efforts to push it. We recommend to not try GA4 for another year or two and even then, only implement in parallel with UA and as a supplemental data source to UA.

**Analytics POV.** The way you implement GA4 properties and streams should come from analysts who will use the data. The analysts should know what kind of business questions they're typically being asked and how they prefer to answer those questions. Are there different stakeholders of different sites or do the stakeholders share the sites? Are the data stakeholders able to use GA4 dashboards on their own? Should they be separately shared?

**Implementation POV.** from the technical perspective, it's a lot easier to implement it just like you said: same property, different streams and be done with it. But the technical view on things is really the least important. Our main aim here is to satisfy the business and the data stakeholders to the best of our ability.

Comment: From the analytics POV, all the data are for the same stakeholders and everybody should be able to view the data from all 4 websites/domains.
Main goals:
1. Create audiences for remarketing, separately for domain.sk and domain.cz visitors
2. See visitors journey across the domains - from domain.sk to domain.com, or domain.cz to domain.com, domain.cz to domain.sk to domain.com...
3. Get as little distorted visitor information as possible for each website

Comment: Well then a good advice here would be to not use GA4 for it then. UA will suffice pretty well. Keep GA4 to gather historical data only.